# Is passing userId to other users in formposts, or get requests a bad idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

My question is quite simple.

I am currently developing a social platform in asp.net mvc5 with identity2.

If I for example create message system and want to send a message to a specific user, is it considered a breach of security to have the userid of the recipient in the form post?

Another example could be a userid in the url, when visiting a profile, or a path to a profile picture like this /uploads/useridofvisiteduser/images/guid.ext.

All userId's in my project is guid's and not integer values.

Is it considered as a breach to expose userid's in that way?

Comment: You are using HTTPS/TLS 1.2, right?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, if you took care of unacceptable values on the server-side.
For example if you get a messageId to delete a message you have to get currently logged in user to make sure he is deleting his own message and not posting someone else message ID to be deleted.

but just in case you can use encryption.
First encrypt the data then url-encode the result and do the reverse at the receiving end (server-side).

Comment: Or use HTTPS for the in transit encryption.

Comment: I am only talking about getting specefic things and using the userid as identifier. As an example path to profile picture that is showed on the visited user,  on /uploads/useridofvisiteduser/images/guid.ext or visitng users profile /profile/uid. I would never send a userid trough a post to change data for the specific user. Its fetched serverside.

Comment: @Velict Then it's no problem at all.